# PHP laravel and JQuery AJAX append form input

Tags: javascript, laravel

Hey guys I am just wondering how I can append a view within Laravel to my page using AJAX.
How can I append just input nema="result" and insert data into the database with laravel.

```
Error: [HTTP/1.1 422 Unprocessable Entity 323ms]
```

My blad file

```
<form id="repeater_form" class="row" action="{{route('agreement.store')}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
@csrf
    <div class="col-sm-3 form-group">
        <label>Year</label>
        <select class="form-control select2"  name="year" >
            <option value="">--select--</option>
            @foreach ($years as $key => $value)
                <option value="{{ $key }}">{{ $value }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label>target</label>
    <input type="text" name="target" id="target" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div id="repeater">
        <div class="repeater-heading" align="right">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary repeater-add-btn">Add More Skill</button>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div class="items" data-group="programming_languages">
        <div class="item-content">
            <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <input type="text" name="result[]" id="result" class="form-control" required />
                <div class="col-md-3" style="margin-top:24px;" align="center">
                <button id="remove-btn" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="$(this).parents('.items').remove()">Remove</button>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
        <button name="insert" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-save"></i> Submit</button>
        <a href="{{route('agreement.index')}}"  class="btn btn-danger"> backe</a>
    </div>
</form>
```

Js File

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#repeater").createRepeater();
        $('#repeater_form').on('submit', function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: '{{route('agreement.store')}}',
                method:"POST",
                data:$(this).serialize(),
                success:function(data)
                {
                    $('#repeater_form')[0].reset();
                    $("#repeater").createRepeater();
                    $('#success_result').html(data);

                }
            });
        });

    });

</script>
```

I am new in laravel Here what am I doing I am going to insert a simple form value into database. Now, what happen when I click on submit button it is not insert data. I have no idea about that. So, How can I do this? Please help me.

Thank You.

My Contoroller

```
public function store(CreateAgreement $request)
{
    $agreements = new Agreement;

    $agreements->target = $request->target;
    $agreements->result = $request->result;

        $agreements->years()->attach(request('year'));
        $agreements->save();
    return redirect()->route('agreement.index');
}
```

CreateAgreement Request

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'year' => ['required'],
            'code' => ['required'],
            'target' => ['required'],
            'result' => ['required'],
        ];
    }
```

**Repeater js**

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    createRepeater: function () {
        var addItem = function (items, key) {
            var itemContent = items;
            var group = itemContent.data("group");
            var item = itemContent;
            var input = item.find('input,select');
            input.each(function (index, el) {
                var attrName = $(el).data('name');
                var skipName = $(el).data('skip-name');
                if (skipName != true) {
                    $(el).attr("name", group + "[" + key + "]" + attrName);
                } else {
                    if (attrName != 'undefined') {
                        $(el).attr("name", attrName);
                    }
                }
            })
            var itemClone = items;

            /* Handling remove btn */
            var removeButton = itemClone.find('.remove-btn');

            if (key == 0) {
                removeButton.attr('disabled', true);
            } else {
                removeButton.attr('disabled', false);
            }

            $("<div class='items'>" + itemClone.html() + "<div/>").appendTo(repeater);
        };
        /* find elements */
        var repeater = this;
        var items = repeater.find(".items");
        var key = 0;
        var addButton = repeater.find('.repeater-add-btn');
        var newItem = items;

        if (key == 0) {
            items.remove();
            addItem(newItem, key);
        }

        /* handle click and add items */
        addButton.on("click", function () {
            key++;
            addItem(newItem, key);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Hey Ezatullah, please add you CreateAgreement request's code too

Comment: check I added CreateAgreement request's code

Comment: the validation seems to be failing with the message 'The code field is required'.

displaying the errors on the page will help you see where its failing. Checkout https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors

Comment: you are going to run into a few problems here. please can you share the createRepeater() function's code too?

Comment: I have this error and also added repeater js check it       Error: [HTTP/1.1 422 Unprocessable Entity 323ms]